# No longer able to enable my network interface in Centos 8

Tags: centos, networking

### Environment

Operating System: CentOS Linux 8
Virtual Machine running on VMWare Workstation 16 Pro on Windows 11 host.

### Question

I recently had an application lockup while using my VM and I had to power down the VM to recover. When I restarted the VM, I no longer had network access. In Gnome, I lost the network section of the settings application, and if I try to enable the interface using `nmtui` I get `Could not activate connection: Connection 'Host NAT' is not available on device ens160 because device is strictly unmanaged`

The device appears in the nmcli status list as type `ethernet` and state `unmanaged`. `ip a` lists the interface with the state UP, but doesn't have an IP address.

I tried:

- `nmcli device set ens160 managed yes` - No change (still shows unmanaged)
- manually editing `ifconfig-ens160` but the settings appear correct
- Restarting the Guest OS
- Restarting the Host OS

One more note: None of the other VMs are showing the same symptoms, so I don't believe its the host OS or the VM configuration.

I can't figure out how to restore my interface. Thoughts?

### Update

The interfaces came up when I resumed the VM this morning, so I still don't know what caused it. To answer Alex's questions however:

ifcfg-ens160:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6_DISABLED=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="Host NAT"
UUID=89af5f75-265c-4766-891e-01003ef5a906
DEVICE=ens160
ONBOOT=yes
```

Output of `nmcli con up ens160`

```
Error: unknown connection 'ens160'.
```

Output of `nmcli con up "Host NAT"`

```
Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/7)
```

Comment: Are there any config files inside etc/NetworkManager/conf.d that contain your network interface ens160?

Comment: @Alex, The folder is empty.

Comment: Please post the contents of the network interface config in network-scripts and post the output of nmcli con up ens160

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by suspending the virtual machine and resuming it. I can't quite explain what happened, but it would appear that VMWare changes the state of the network interfaces when suspending a VM and in my case, it wasn't resumed properly. I've had it happen a second time and the suspend/resume approach solved it again.

Comment: This works for me. But can't explain either what was the problem. Probably a bug in VMWare.

Answer (score 0):

Did you clone your VM? I had also the same issue and the same solution worked. In my case I had cloned a VM from the existing Linux VM. Its better to do basic configuration of the Primary VM from which you will be cloning. The following article is a little old but addresses the same context.
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2002767
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```shell
nmcli n off
```

then

```shell
nmcli n on
```

It worked for me when I shutdown an CentOS8 then turn it on, the network interface (in this case `ens160`) couldn't be up and have error "device lo not available because device is stricly unmanaged" from NetworkManager.

Comment: Was that really device `Io` (upper-case `i`)? The loopback device is usually called `lo` (lower-case `L`).